# Python - Get current dir of file opened with glob using wildcards

Tags: pandas, dataframe, directory, export-to-csv, glob

I'm using glob() to read all files in a directory. I need to read every csv file in all subfolders. After I read and process each file I want to save every new file in another folder but keep the subfolder name. To open the files I use:

```
data = "data/**/*.csv"
csv_files = glob(data, recursive=True)
```

Then I read each file:

```
for f in csv_files:
        file = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';')
        
        fileName = os.path.basename(f)
        path = os.path.dirname(data)
        fileFolder = os.path.basename(path)

#       Do some stuff
#
#       Then save the file

        file.to_csv("new_data/"+fileFolder+fileName)
```

My problem is `fileFolder` returns ** instead of the actual folder name

My source dir looks like:

```
data / 
       - January 2021
       - February 2021
             .
             .
             .
       - December 2021
```

And I want to save my files under

```
new_data / 
       - January 2021
       - February 2021
             .
             .
             .
       - December 2021
```

I'm looking for a way where I don't need to manually create a list with all the subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for f in csv_files:
    file = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';')
        
#    Do some stuff
#
#    Then save the file

    new_path = os.path.join(*f.split(os.path.sep)[1:])
    file.to_csv(os.path.join('new_data', *new_path))
```

What that does is it

1. Splits the path of the file by `/` on macOS/Linux and `\` on Windows
2. Removes the first one (the topmost-level directory)
3. Joins it back together with `'new_data'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer but it throws this error: `[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\F\\l\\o\\a\\t\\R\\e\\p\\o\\r\\t\\_\\2\\0\\2\\1\\0\\2\\0\\1\\.\\c\\s\\v'`

However, using:

`new_path = (f.split(os.path.sep)[-2])`

It works but only if I want to create one level. It solves my problem, but I'll try to look for a solution for any amount of subfolders.

Comment: Ooops, that's a funny mistake! Can you show me a sample of `f`?